# Have supporters of "right-wing populist" parties in Europe explained why they trust Trump?

Tags: donald-trump, parties, europe, public-opinion

According to a [Pew survey/study](https://www.pewresearch.org/global/2018/10/01/trumps-international-ratings-remain-low-especially-among-key-allies/), supporters of "right-wing populist" parties (by which they mean e.g. UKIP, FN of France, Northern League in Italy, or AfD in Germany) have more confidence in Trump to "do the right thing regarding world affairs" compared to average person from the same European country (of that party).

[image]

Given Trump's ["America first"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America_First_(policy)#History_under_President_Trump) policy (or at least slogan), why would supporters of nationalistic parties in Europe trust Trump to "do the right thing *regarding world affairs*" (more than other Europeans do)? Are there any surveys or at least qualitative studies (like interviews etc.) among supporters of "right-wing populist" parties (as defined above) which shed any light on the reasons for this confidence?

(I can see UKIP being a special case here due to Trump promising post-Brexit trade deals with the UK etc. But what about the "right-wing populist" parties in the rest of the EU?)

Comment: If I'm reading the graph correctly, 59% of swedes, 65% of french, 44% of italians, 56% of dutch and 69% of german so called "supporters of right wing populist parties" hold ambigious views towards Trump, and have the relative majority of these groups, being more numerous than people being either favorable or against Trump. Only in the UK there'd be a clear majority towards Trump. Your premise is, as such, wrong. I could have misinterpreted the graph.

Comment: By occasion - isn't term populist quite emotionally loaded and not specially accurate? Example: when German gov closed its nuclear plants and compensated that with imported electricity from fossil fuels (more expensive AND increased CO2 emission), while AfD was one of few oddballs who against public pressure claimed it was a bad move.

Comment: [German Wikipedia disagrees with your assessment](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomausstieg#Versorgungssicherheit_und_Stromimporte).

Comment: @Jan: what do you mean (with that link)?

Comment: @Fizz I meant Shadow’s comment.

Comment: It may be about (an expectation of) honesty. If he's honest about putting america above [country], then IF he says something positive about [country], it's likely true. If there's one global issue people on the right have about politicians, it's a lack of honesty, hence why they tend to vote for newer parties.

Comment: The title (though not the body) and some of the comments here dwell too much on "trust" in the honest vs. dishonest sense. Pretty much nobody trusts Trump in his personal capacity as an honest person (though some appreciate his bluntness), but they can still believe he'll do something they agree with when they largely agree with him in general.

Comment: Don't expect consistency from ideologists.

Answer (score 25):

I think that you are looking at too much rational level concerning people's reaction. Look a bit more at ideology:

- Whoever shares your views (whichever they are), would seem to you be a nice, trustworthy person who would do lot's of good in the world. There would be also a grain of truth in it, as it would be easier to get on with like minded people. In the linked PEW research there were also data hard to explain by actual track record (but possible by tribal logic) why Obama had sky high popularity in the same countries.
- Mainstream media bashing Trump for clicks and making breaking news out of every dumb tweet... while people voting those parties already nicely call mainstream media as ex. *Lügenpresse* (German: lying press) and consider as worthless propaganda. By virtue of not being bombarded with such clickbaits and simplified moral stories, where Trump is the main villain, they would have much more positive opinion about him than the rest of society.
- Same perception of main global threats: mass migration and hollowing out of the economy by moving production abroad. I understand that from logic perspective it may look odd, but for a nationalists openly saying "[My country] first", sounds simply like expressing obvious, rational self interest and not sinister. So the guy is honest enough to say that for him interests of his country are the priority and is willing to actually deal with those global issues that electorate consider as the main problem.

Comment: "Are there any surveys or at least qualitative studies" is sort of key to the question; the above lacks references.  I mean, the explanation "NAZIs like NAZIs" is really simple and obvious, but I don't think it is a good answer to the posed question, without citations of some kind.

Comment: @Yakk The problem is that generally "studies" on this issue that I found were effectively "who radicalised you?" and "why are you so evil?". If you expect some so called "authoritative sources", I could provide you a link to WaPo opinion piece on "nationalist international", but personally have an impression that they don't understand the phenomena well: https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/global-opinions/right-wing-extremists-are-a-global-problem-they-need-a-global-response/2019/08/19/51166e60-be07-11e9-b873-63ace636af08_story.html

Comment: Sure, but "I cannot answer this question with a good answer, because the information to do so does not exist" is a good response to a question you cannot find solid information on.  The action item from that is then ... not answering the question.

Comment: @Yakk The question suggest studies, but does not require them. In order not be in echo chamber I watch their "primary sources" from time to time, so I get the mindset quite well. The caveat that I'd put is, that I present general picture, while there should be some serious local differences, as at least in theory Alternative für Deutschland started as highly pro-free market party, while Front National had economically rather left wing agenda but supports protectionism. I don't know how it in practice translates to opinion on Trump.

Comment: They don't "nicely call mainstream media as ex. Lügenpresse." Even among right-wing parties, almost only neo-Nazis use that particular phrase, and there's nothing nice about it.

Comment: "nicely call mainstream media as ex. Lügenpresse" Is "ex." short for "example"? If so, it should be "nicely call mainstream media Lügenpresse, for example"

Comment: @Obie2.0 Apparently German media published poll saying something like 20% of questioned use this term: https://www.welt.de/politik/deutschland/article148286129/Jeder-Fuenfte-nennt-deutsche-Medien-Luegenpresse.html (in the West there seems to be a general collapse of trust in media, so I'd not be so sure about political views of people who use this term)

Comment: Prompting people can easily elicit anomalous responses, particularly among people who don't know the history behind the term. A more pertinent question would be what percentage use it spontaneously. And we are talking about a survey in Germany, so as for the remainder of that 20%,  a non-trivial percentage of the population having Nazi sympathies can't be entirely ruled out.

Comment: "I think that you are looking at too much rational level " So which of the reasons you offer aren't "rational level" to you?

Comment: @Hasse1987 Nationalists don't have a track record of being able to cooperate well with each other, and I don't mean WW2, but problems to form a coherent faction in Europarliament. While Brexiters are flattered by encouraging Trump rhetoric, somehow he looks to me as not the best person to ask for generous trade deal. ;) So unless they would be anyway unified by common enemies or morph in to less divisive ideology (ex. white nationalism), on rational (common interests and goals) level the friendship looks as fragile at best.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Sure, Germany can have right now support for Nazis comparable to results they got in 1930 election. (As Polish, shall I express my the uttermost respect for great German nation or should I better flee when I still can?  ;)  ) Nevertheless, the linked article hints to something much more mundane - 42% of Germans have generally doubts about credibility of their media, so I don't see anything shocking that half of this number expressed it in explicit way.

Comment: @Shadow1024 My question was, which of the points you presented in your answer are not in your view "rational level"? Since your first sentence says that the nationalists' actions can't be explained by looking at things "rational level"?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to shared views and media effects, you should consider elite cueing: mass opinions are affected by the views of national (party) elites. There is quite some academic (also empirical) literature about it, e.g. here https://rubenson.org/wp-content/uploads/2019/11/merkley-stecula.pdf (US) or here https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S026137941200128X (EU)